# AEM::Dispatcher issue

Tags: apache, aem

I have configured dispatcher on my local on AEM and now trying the URL http://www.mywebapp.com (this entry is made in hosts file too). Here is the error that I am getting

```
[Tue Mar 10 12:25:43 2015] [D] [7268(496)] Found farm website for www.mywebapp.com
[Tue Mar 10 12:25:43 2015] [D] [7268(496)] checking [/]
[Tue Mar 10 12:25:43 2015] [D] [7268(496)] request URL has no extension: /
[Tue Mar 10 12:25:43 2015] [D] [7268(496)] cache-action for [/]: NONE
[Tue Mar 10 12:25:43 2015] [D] [7268(496)] Filter rejects: GET / HTTP/1.1
[Tue Mar 10 12:25:43 2015] [I] [7268(496)] "GET /" - - 1ms
```

Here is the dispatcher.any file. I am not sure what filter is exactly blocking the request:

```
# Each farm configures a set of load balanced renders (i.e. remote servers)
/farms
  {
  # First farm entry
  /website 
    {  
    # Request headers that should be forwarded to the remote server.
    /clientheaders
      {
      # Forward all request headers that are end-to-end. If you want
      # to forward a specific set of headers, you'll have to list
      # them here.
      "*"
      }

    # Hostname globbing for farm selection (virtual domain addressing)
    /virtualhosts
      {
      # Entries will be compared against the "Host" request header
      # and an optional request URL prefix.
      #
      # Examples:
      #
      #   www.company.com
      #   intranet.*
      #   myhost:8888/mysite
      "*"
      }

    # The load will be balanced among these render instances
    /renders
      {
      /rend01
        {
        # Hostname or IP of the render
        /hostname "127.0.0.1"
        # Port of the render
        /port "4503"
        # Connect timeout in milliseconds, 0 to wait indefinitely
        # /timeout "0"
        }
      }

    # The filter section defines the requests that should be handled by the dispatcher.
    # The globs will be compared against the request line, e.g. "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1".
    /filter
      {
      # Deny everything first and then allow specific entries
      /0001 { /type "deny"  /glob "*" }

      # Open consoles
#     /0011 { /type "allow" /glob "* /admin/*"  }  # allow servlet engine admin
#     /0012 { /type "allow" /glob "* /crx/*"    }  # allow content repository
#     /0013 { /type "allow" /glob "* /system/*" }  # allow OSGi console

      # Allow non-public content directories
#     /0021 { /type "allow" /glob "* /apps/*"   }  # allow apps access
#     /0022 { /type "allow" /glob "* /bin/*"    }
      /0023 { /type "allow" /glob "* /content*" }  # disable this rule to allow mapped content only

#     /0024 { /type "allow" /glob "* /libs/*"   }
#     /0025 { /type "deny"  /glob "* /libs/shindig/proxy*" } # if you enable /libs close access to proxy

#     /0026 { /type "allow" /glob "* /home/*"   }
#     /0027 { /type "allow" /glob "* /tmp/*"    }
#     /0028 { /type "allow" /glob "* /var/*"    }

      # Enable specific mime types in non-public content directories 
      /0041 { /type "allow" /glob "* *.css *"   }  # enable css
      /0042 { /type "allow" /glob "* *.gif *"   }  # enable gifs
      /0043 { /type "allow" /glob "* *.ico *"   }  # enable icos
      /0044 { /type "allow" /glob "* *.js *"    }  # enable javascript
      /0045 { /type "allow" /glob "* *.png *"   }  # enable png
      /0046 { /type "allow" /glob "* *.swf *"   }  # enable flash
      /0047 { /type "allow" /glob "* *.html *"   }  # enable flash

      # Enable features 
      /0061 { /type "allow" /glob "POST /content/[.]*.form.html" }  # allow POSTs to form selectors under content
      /0062 { /type "allow" /glob "* /libs/cq/personalization/*"  }  # enable personalization

      # Deny content grabbing
      /0081 { /type "deny"  /glob "GET *.infinity.json*" }
      /0082 { /type "deny"  /glob "GET *.tidy.json*"     }
      /0083 { /type "deny"  /glob "GET *.sysview.xml*"   }
      /0084 { /type "deny"  /glob "GET *.docview.json*"  }
      /0085 { /type "deny"  /glob "GET *.docview.xml*"  }

      /0086 { /type "deny"  /glob "GET *.*[0-9].json*" }
#     /0087 { /type "allow" /glob "GET *.1.json*" }          # allow one-level json requests

      # Deny query
      /0090 { /type "deny"  /glob "* *.query.json*" }
      }

    # The cache section regulates what responses will be cached and where.
    /cache
      {
      # The docroot must be equal to the document root of the webserver. The
      # dispatcher will store files relative to this directory and subsequent
      # requests may be "declined" by the dispatcher, allowing the webserver
      # to deliver them just like static files.
      /docroot "C:/Apache2.2/htdocs"

      # Sets the level upto which files named ".stat" will be created in the 
      # document root of the webserver. When an activation request for some 
      # page is received, only files within the same subtree are affected 
      # by the invalidation.
      /statfileslevel "3"

      # Flag indicating whether to cache responses to requests that contain
      # authorization information.
      /allowAuthorized "1"

      # Flag indicating whether the dispatcher should serve stale content if
      # no remote server is available.
      #/serveStaleOnError "0"

      # The rules section defines what responses should be cached based on
      # the requested URL. Please note that only the following requests can
      # lead to cacheable responses:
      #
      # - HTTP method is GET
      # - URL has an extension
      # - Request has no query string
      # - Request has no "Authorization" header (unless allowAuthorized is 1)
      /rules
        {
        /0000
          {
          # the globbing pattern to be compared against the url
          # example: *             -> everything
          #        : /foo/bar.*    -> only the /foo/bar documents
          #        : /foo/bar/*    -> all pages below /foo/bar
          #        : /foo/bar[./]* -> all pages below and /foo/bar itself
          #        : *.html        -> all .html files
          /glob "*"
          /type "allow"
          }
        }

      # The invalidate section defines the pages that are "invalidated" after
      # any activation. Please note that the activated page itself and all 
      # related documents are flushed on an modification. For example: if the 
      # page /foo/bar is activated, all /foo/bar.* files are removed from the
      # cache.
      /invalidate
        {
        /0000
          {
          /glob "*"
          /type "deny"
          }
        /0001
          {
          # Consider all HTML files stale after an activation.
          /glob "*.html"
          /type "allow"
          }
        }

      # The allowedClients section restricts the client IP addresses that are
      # allowed to issue activation requests.
      /allowedClients
        {
        # Uncomment the following to restrict activation requests to originate
        # from "localhost" only.
        #
        #/0000
        #  {
        #  /glob "*"
        #  /type "deny"
        #  }
        #/0001
        #  {
        #  /glob "127.0.0.1"
        #  /type "allow"
        #  }
        }
      }

    # The statistics sections dictates how the load should be balanced among the
    # renders according to the media-type. 
    /statistics
      {
      /categories
        {
        /html
          {
          /glob "*.html"
          }
        /others
          {
          /glob "*"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: not sure about the error, but the first filter rule blocks everything and the later rules allow some exceptions: /0001 { /type "deny"  /glob "*" }

Comment: Thanks for the response. I know that's the way dispatcher filter works. I am not able to understand what rule is blocking the GET /

Comment: What I meant is, the rule I mentioned would block your GET /

Comment: So, what do you think what rule should I put in place that would allow GET /

Comment: I am not an expert with the Dispatcher, but as you are on your local instance, you could try to just use /0001 { /type "allow" /glob "*" }

Answer (score 3):

you should have mod_rewrite redirecting your "GET /" request to "GET /content/mywebapp/en.html" (among other rules). 
"GET /" can't be cached, because it doesn't have any extension, and you probably want your home page to be cached.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options, either setup apache to redirect / to your homepage (/content/myapp/home.html or the equivalent)
OR you can use resource resolver factory settings to rewrite the url.

For the simple version, use resource resolver mappings.  See this post for more details:

http://www.aemmastery.com/2015/03/15/aem-osgi-service-dive-resource-resolver-factory/

Answer (score 1):

You may need a vhost file similar to the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.mywebapp.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorDocument 404 /content/mywebapp/en/404.html
    ErrorDocument 500 /content/mywebapp/en/500.html

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteLog "logs/rewrite-www-mywebapp-com.log"
    RewriteLogLevel 1

    RewriteRule ^/en.html$ / [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^/$ /content/mywebapp/en.html [PT]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/etc(.*) [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/libs(.*) [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/content(.*) [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/system(.*) [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dam(.*) [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/services(.*) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^/(.*) /content/mywebapp/$1 [PT]

    <Directory "/var/www/html">
        <IfModule disp_apache2.c>
            SetHandler dispatcher-handler
            ModMimeUsePathInfo On
        </IfModule>

            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride AuthConfig
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

So, if you go to www.mywebapp.com, file /var/www/html/content/mywebapp/en.html is created and cached.
If you go to www.mywebbapp.com/en/foo/bar.html,
file /var/www/html/content/mywebapp/en/foo/bar.html is created and cached.

Customize the above file to meet your own needs.

You may also need to configure /etc/mapping to fit your URL rewriting needs. Refer to this page for more information:
https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/deploy/configuring/resource-mapping.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example we did for one of the taining sites

```html
 # first farm entry (label is not important, just for your convenience)
  /cookbook
    {
    # client headers which should be passed through to the render instances
    # (feature supported since dispatcher build 2.6.3.5222)
    /clientheaders
      {
      "referer"
      "user-agent"
      "authorization"
      "from"
      "content-type"
      "content-length"
      "accept-charset"
      "accept-encoding"
      "accept-language"
      "accept"
      "host"
      "if-match"
      "if-none-match"
      "if-range"
      "if-unmodified-since"
      "max-forwards"
      "proxy-authorization"
      "proxy-connection"
      "range"
      "cookie"
      "cq-action"
      "cq-handle"
      "handle"
      "action"
      "cqstats"
      "depth"
      "translate"
      "expires"
      "date"
      "dav"
      "ms-author-via"
      "if"
      "lock-token"
      "x-expected-entity-length"
      "destination"
      }
    # hostname globbing for farm selection (virtual domain addressing)
    /virtualhosts
      {
      # entries will be compared against the 'host' request header.
      # example: www.company.com
      # example: intranet.*
      "*"
      }
    # the load will be balanced among these render instances
    /renders
      {
      /publish1
        {
        # hostname or IP of the render
        /hostname "localhost"
        # port of the render
        /port "4503"
        # connect timeout in milliseconds, 0 to wait indefinitely
        /timeout "0"
        }
      }
    # only handle the requests in the following acl. default is 'none'
    # the glob pattern is matched against the first request line
    /filter
      {
      # deny everything and allow specific entries
      /0001 { /type "deny"  /glob "*" }

      # open consoles
 #    /0012 { /type "allow" /glob "* /crx/*"    }  # allow content repository
 #    /0013 { /type "allow" /glob "* /system/*" }  # allow OSGi console

      # allow non-public content directories
 #    /0021 { /type "allow" /glob "* /apps/*"   }  # allow apps access
      /0022 { /type "allow" /glob "* /bin/*"    }
      /0023 { /type "allow" /glob "* /content*" }  # disable this rule to allow mapped content only

 #    /0024 { /type "allow" /glob "* /libs/*"   }
 #    /0025 { /type "deny"  /glob "* /libs/shindig/proxy*" } # if you enable /libs close access to proxy

 #    /0026 { /type "allow" /glob "* /home/*"   }
 #    /0027 { /type "allow" /glob "* /tmp/*"    }
 #    /0028 { /type "allow" /glob "* /var/*"    }

      # enable specific mime types in non-public content directories
      /0041 { /type "allow" /glob "* *.css *"   }  # enable css
      /0042 { /type "allow" /glob "* *.gif *"   }  # enable gifs
      /0043 { /type "allow" /glob "* *.ico *"   }  # enable icos
      /0044 { /type "allow" /glob "* *.js *"    }  # enable javascript
      /0045 { /type "allow" /glob "* *.png *"   }  # enable png
      /0046 { /type "allow" /glob "* *.swf *"   }  # enable flash
      /0047 { /type "allow" /glob "* *.svg *"   }  # enable SVG
      /0048 { /type "allow" /glob "* *.woff *"  }  # enable woff
      /0049 { /type "allow" /glob "* *.ttf *"   }  # enable ttf
      /0050 { /type "allow" /glob "* *.eot *"   }  # enable eot
      /0051 { /type "allow" /glob "* *.jpg *"   }  # enable jpg

      /0052 { /type "allow" /glob "* /services/*" } # enable servlet services

      # enable features
      /0061 { /type "allow" /glob "POST /content/[.]*.form.html" }  # allow POSTs to form selectors under content
      /0062 { /type "allow" /glob "* /libs/cq/personalization/*" }  # enable personalization

      # deny content grabbing
      /0081 { /type "deny"  /glob "GET *.infinity.json*" }
      /0082 { /type "deny"  /glob "GET *.tidy.json*"     }
      /0083 { /type "deny"  /glob "GET *.sysview.xml*"   }
      /0084 { /type "deny"  /glob "GET *.docview.json*"  }
      /0085 { /type "deny"  /glob "GET *.docview.xml*"   }
      /0086 { /type "deny"  /glob "GET *.*[0-9].json*"   }
      /0087 { /type "deny"  /glob "GET *.feed.xml*"      }
 #    /0088 { /type "allow" /glob "GET *.1.json*"        }  # allow one-level json requests
      /0089 { /type "allow" /glob "GET /etc/clientcontext/.*/*.json*.*" }

      # deny query
      /0090 { /type "deny"  /glob "* *.query.json*" }
      }

    # allow propagation of replication posts (should seldomly be used)
    /propagateSyndPost "0"

    # the cache is used to store requests from the renders for faster delivery
    # for a second time.
    /cache
      {
      # the cacheroot must be equal to the document root of the webserver
      /docroot "/var/www/html/content/cookbook"

      # sets the level upto which files named ".stat" will be created in the
      # document root of the webserver. when an activation request for some
      # handle is received, only files within the same subtree are affected
      # by the invalidation.
      /statfileslevel "0"
      # caches also authorized data
      /allowAuthorized "1"

      # the rules define, which pages should be cached. please note that
      # - only GET requests are cached
      # - only requests with an extension are cached
      # - only requests without query parameters ( ? ) are cached
      # - only unauthorized pages are cached unless allowUnauthorized is set to 1
      /rules
        {
        /0000
          {
          # the globbing pattern to be compared against the url
          # example: *       -> everything
          #     : /foo/bar.*    -> only the /foo/bar documents
          #     : /foo/bar/*    -> all pages below /foo/bar
          #     : /foo/bar[./]* -> all pages below and /foo/bar itself
          #     : *.html        -> all .html files
          /glob "*"
          /type "allow"
          }
        }
      # the invalidate section defines those pages which are 'invalidated' after
      # any activation. please note that, the activated page itself and all
      # related documents are flushed on an modification. for example: if the
      # page /foo/bar is activated, all /foo/bar.* files are removed from the
      # cache.
      /invalidate
        {
        /0000
          {
          /glob "*"
          /type "deny"
          }
        /0001
          {
          /glob "*.html"
          /type "allow"
          }
        }
      }
    # the statistics define, how the load should be balanced among the renders
    # according to the media-type.
    /statistics
      {
      /categories
        {
        /html
          {
          /glob "*.html"
          }
        /others
          {
          /glob "*"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

By default you are not allowing anything using this filter.

```
# Deny everything first and then allow specific entries
/0001 { /type "deny"  /glob "*" }
```

Hence / is not allowed. If you want to allow access to root you need to specifically allow it by adding the line

```
/0024 { /type "allow" /glob "* /*" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your dispatcher config looks fine. To verify whether dispatcher is working or not, you can simply enter the following url to see if page is showing up, then check the cache folder.

> http://localhost:{port if you are not using 80 on apache)/content/{sitenode}

Assume everything above-mentioned is working when use the localhost, it must be the configuration issue in your apache config file.

Check the following settings carefully defined in your dispatcher module section

- DispatcherDeclineRoot (This defines whether to decline requests to the root "/")
- DispatcherUseProcessedURL (This defines whether to use pre-processed URLs for all further processing by Dispatcher)

p.s. If you make it working, don't forget to share some details here. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use mod_rewrite Apache Module in order to redirect your request from '/' to '/content/'/en.html'
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html
This official documentation provides good read regarding how to write rewrite rules.

apart from this, because / doesn't have any extension, it says that this request can't be cached.
I believe you won't need to do anything else apart from redirection mentioned, because en.html has '.html' as it's extension and /0047 { /type "allow" /glob "* *.html *"   } is already mentioned in the Filter section

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways we can resolve it.

1, In filter section add the below rule.
  `/0001 { /type "allow"  /glob "*" }`

2, normally in real time projects we have content under /content/xyz.html, for this kind of scenario we add below rules.

```
`/0001 { /type "deny"  /glob "*" }`
`/0001 { /type "allow"  /glob "/content/*" }`
```

Add a rewrite rule which any thing after URL redirect to /content/xyz.html.

RewriteRule ^/(.*) /content/mywebapp/$1 [R=301, L]

keep adding deny and allow rules as per the project requirements.